# Shortening many if statements in a while loop in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, subtraction

How can I shorten many subtractions of the exact same nature in a while loop in Java? I feel like it's very redundant and there can definitely be a shorter way.

```
while (x != 0) {
        if (x - 100 >= 0) {
            x -= 100;
        }

        if (x - 50 >= 0) {
            x -= 50;
        }

        if (x - 25 >= 0) {
            x -= 25;
        }

        ...
```

Comment: Are you aware that, as currently written, it might be possible for _more_ than one `if` statement to fire?  If so, is this your actual intention?

Comment: Why don't you check for `if (x >= 100)` instead of `if  (x - 100 >= 0)`? Also, can you be sure that `x` will eventually be 0?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes this is my intention

Comment: @maloomeister For clarity sake on my end since x will definitely be 0 at some point since x is made up of the numbers I have stated in the if statements :) But your recommendation is cleaner thank you

Comment: Since you can trigger more than one if-statement, I'm not sure how it could be shortened.

Comment: @user745587 Post the whole code, If we see what type of problem you are solving there might be more optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to subtract and compare to zero, instead just compare to the number you are subtracting.

```java
while (x != 0) {
        if (x >= 100) {
            x -= 100;
        }

        if (x >= 50) {
            x -= 50;
        }

        if (x >= 25) {
            x -= 25;
        }

        ...
```

Secondly, what you're asking is a case by case problem. You could shorten the code above like this:

```java
int[] nums = {100, 50, 25};

while (x != 0) {
    for (int num : nums) {
        if (x >= num) {
            x -= num;
        }
    }
}
```